# svn-tag Hudson plugin not working

Tags: java, svn, hudson

I started using Hudson a week ago. I was able to add various plugins to my build cycle (like ci-game, email-ext and Sonar) but i am unable to get the svn-tag to work.

I am using the latest version of the Hudson war (2.2.0) and the version 1.16 of the Subversion Tagging Plugin.

When a build fails test the plugin tells me that it didn't do anything (since the build failed) but, when the build runs fine the plugin tells me nothing.

Checking http://myserver/hudson/log/all i can see the following stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Executor threw an exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getRootBuild()Lhudson/model/AbstractBuild;
    at hudson.plugins.svn_tag.SvnTagPlugin.perform(SvnTagPlugin.java:79)
    at hudson.plugins.svn_tag.SvnTagPublisher.perform(SvnTagPublisher.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
    at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608)
    at     hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:835)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1409)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:414)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Am i missing something ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a difference between hudson CI and jenkins CI. Jenkins provides the method `hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getRootBuild()` while, according to the java doc, it is not part of hudson.

- [JavaDoc for AbstractBuild at jenkins](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html)
- [JavaDoc for AbstractBuild at hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html)

The plugin may not be compatible with oracle hudson CI.

Comment: Hi Andreas_D, thanks for your help. I was led to install the svn-tag plugin into Hudson because Hudson itself listed it as an available plugin. It seems now that listing it does not mean it will necessarily work, that's not good. Anyway, besides moving to Jenkins (i am considering) are there any other options to tag successful builds using Hudson ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I just did a research on your question ;)

Comment: Just for the record: i've switched to Jenkins. It was a smooth transition and the plugin now works fine.

Comment: Great to hear it! (transition to jenkins and that it works now ;) )